# Subplots are different sizes

Tags: matlab, subplot

I create figures with 5x3 subplots, every iteration, another 3 figures is added per column and every iteration, the previous three plots shrink a little more.

This is my code:

```
for i=1:4%for every station
   figure
    for j=1:sSelect %for every storm
        Hm0=eval(strcat('Hm0',Wavenames(i),'C'));%create data
        Tz=eval(strcat('Tz',Wavenames(i),'C'));
        Tp=eval(strcat('Tp',Wavenames(i),'C'));
        Ti=numericdates.(Wavenames(i));
        ix=Ti>Selectnum(j,1)-numMore & Ti<Selectnum(j,2)+numMore; %index of dates numMore hours before and after the storm
        
        Hm0Plot=Hm0(ix); %create data that needs to be plotted
        TzPlot=Tz(ix);
        TpPlot=Tp(ix);
        TPlot= datetime(Ti(ix),'ConvertFrom','datenum');%dates
        
        if ~isempty(TPlot) 
            
            subplot(3,5,j)
            plot(TPlot,Hm0Plot)
            xlabel('Date')
            ylabel('Hm0 (m)')
            xtickformat('dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')
         
            subplot(3,5,j+5)
            plot(TPlot,TzPlot)
            xtickformat('dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')
            xlabel('Date')
            ylabel('Tz0 (1/s)')


            subplot(3,5,j+10)
            plot(TPlot,TpPlot)
      xtickformat('dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')
            xlabel('Date')
            ylabel('Tp (1/s)')

            suptitle(Wavenames(i))
        end
    end
end
```

This creates 4 figures that all have the same problem and look like this:

[image]

**How do I make all the subplots have the same size?**

Comment: That looks very weird, never seen such a result. What version of MATLAB are you on? If this is reproducible in the latest version, you should submit a bug report.

Comment: Try to remove the Date labels (`xlabel`) see if that temporarily fixes it

Comment: @CrisLuengo matlab R2020a

Comment: @AnderBiguri it's not the xlabel that's the problem. But you did give me an idea. Apperently, this happens because I plot the suptitle 4 times. If I remove it from the loop (see answer) I fix the problem

Comment: Not relevant to your issue but it is better to use [`sgtitle`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sgtitle.html) if you have R2018b or later. `suptitle` requires bio-informatics toolbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the command `suptitle` is in the loop. If I put it outside of the loop, it works.

```
for i=1:4%for every station


 figure
    for j=1:sSelect %for every storm
        Hm0=eval(strcat('Hm0',Wavenames(i),'C'));%Hm0BanyulsC
        Tz=eval(strcat('Tz',Wavenames(i),'C'));%TzBanyulsC
        Tp=eval(strcat('Tp',Wavenames(i),'C'));%TpBanyulsC
        Ti=numericdates.(Wavenames(i));
        ix=Ti>Selectnum(j,1)-numMore & Ti<Selectnum(j,2)+numMore; %index of dates numMore hours before and after the storm
    
    Hm0Plot=Hm0(ix);
    TzPlot=Tz(ix);
    TpPlot=Tp(ix);
    TPlot= datetime(Ti(ix),'ConvertFrom','datenum');
    
    if ~isempty(TPlot)
        
        subplot(3,5,j)
        plot(TPlot,Hm0Plot)
        xlabel('Date')
        ylabel('Hm0 (m)')
        xtickformat('dd-MM-yyyy')
      %  title(strcat('Storm',string(j)))

        subplot(3,5,j+5)
        plot(TPlot,TzPlot)
        xtickformat('dd-MM-yyyy')
        xlabel('Date')
        ylabel('Tz0 (1/s)')


        subplot(3,5,j+10)
        plot(TPlot,TpPlot)
        xtickformat('dd-MM-yyyy')
        xlabel('Date')
        ylabel('Tp (1/s)')

       
    end
    
end
suptitle(Wavenames(i))
end
```